# using mvc route constraints so a url can only be mapped to one of three possible params

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "myaccount/monitor/{category}", // Matches
                new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = (string)null }
);
```

I would like to add a constraint so the category can only match a null or one of three params (i.e. overview, projection, history)

Comment: I personally prefer having three separate routes instead of using route constraints.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `UrlParameter.Optional` to allow nulls, and also use the `constraints` parameter of the [`MapRoute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460520%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)..

```
 routes.MapRoute(null,
                      "myaccount/monitor/{category}", // Matches
                      new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = UrlParameter.Optional  },
                      new { category = "overview|projection|history"}
            );
```

Answer (score 3):

The inline Regex Gaby posted would work. Another way to do it is to define a custom IRouteConstraint:

```
public class FromValuesListConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private List<string> _values;

    public FromValuesListConstraint(params string[] values)
    {
        this._values = values.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string value = values[parameterName].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return _values.Contains(string.Empty);
        }

        return _values.Contains(value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Then pass in an instance of the constraint into your MapRoute call:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "myaccount/monitor/{category}", // Matches
new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = UrlParameter.Optional  },
new { category = new FromValuesListConstraint ("overview", "projection", "history", string.Empty) }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to use separate routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Monitor",
                      "myaccount/monitor", // Matches
                      new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor" }
            );

routes.MapRoute("MonitorHistory",
                      "myaccount/monitor/history", // Matches
                      new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = "history" }
            );

routes.MapRoute("MonitorOverview",
                      "myaccount/monitor/overview", // Matches
                      new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = "overview" }
            );

routes.MapRoute("MonitorProjection",
                      "myaccount/monitor/projection", // Matches
                      new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = "projection" }
            );
```

***Alternately***, you may want to do something like:

```
routes.MapRoute("MonitorGlobal",
                      "myaccount/monitor/{category}", // Matches
                      new { controller = "MyAccount", action = "Monitor", category = string.Empty }
            );
```

And then in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Monitor(string category)
{
    switch (category)
    {
        case string.Empty:
            // do something
            break;

        case "overview":
            // do something
            break;

        // so on and so forth

        default:
            // no match, handle accordingly
            break;
    }
}
```